# NSRunLoopCommonModes constant in RoboVM

Tags: robovm

RoboVM used to include a [method ModeCommon() on the NSRunLoop object](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robovm/robovm-cocoatouch/0.0.11/org/robovm/apple/foundation/NSRunLoop.java#NSRunLoop.ModeCommon%28%29) for access to the NSRunLoopCommonModes constant. That method was removed in later versions. Can I still get access to this constant with the current version of RoboVM? Or can I just hard-code someone String-value? I tried simply using the String 
"NSRunLoopCommonModes", but it doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

This has been moved to [NSRunLoopMode.class](https://github.com/robovm/robovm/blob/master/cocoatouch/src/main/java/org/robovm/apple/foundation/NSRunLoopMode.java) (NSRunLoopMode.Common)